# socketio in python

Tags: django, python-2.7, socket.io, gevent, gevent-socketio

Kindly help me in configuring the socketio in my django module. Am using windows7 OS

*File wsgi.py*

**Sample Code** - `from socketio import SocketIOServer`

**Error** - `Unresolved import:SocketIOServer`

Am new to python and Django Frameworks.!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> pip install socketIO-server

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is `from socketio.server import SocketIOServer`

Comment: Yes, But still the same Error, Unresolved import:SocketIOServer

Comment: Do you have SocketIOServer installed? The normal method for doing so [is via PIP](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip).

Comment: Michael, I have added socket.io.js file under static folder.

Comment: That's not what you want. That's the JavaScript implementation of of SocketIO. You need the Python library. Please see my comment above about using PIP.

Comment: I added the gevent-socketio-0.3.5-rc2, socketIO-client-0.3 libraries, but still the error.

Comment: Again, install it with pip!

Comment: See this how to install pip: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/win/#distribute-pip